# GGplot: Two stacked bar plots side by side (not facets)

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-bar, facet-wrap

I am trying to recreate this solution using `ggplot2` in R: [Combining two stacked bar plots for a grouped stacked bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014596/combining-two-stacked-bar-plots-for-a-grouped-stacked-bar-plot)

```
diamonds %>% 
  filter(color=="D"|color=="E"|color=="F") %>% 
  mutate(dummy=rep(c("a","b"),each=13057)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=color,y=price))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=clarity),stat="identity",width=.25)+
  facet_wrap(~cut)
```

[image]

I added a new variable to the `diamonds` dataset called `dummy`.  `dummy` has two values: `a` and `b`.  Let's say I want to compare these two values by creating a bar graph that has two stacked bars right next to each other (one for each value of `dummy`) for each value of `color`.  How can I manipulate this such that there are two stacked bars for each value of `color`?

I think it would involve `position dodge` and/or a separate `legend`, but I've been unsuccessful so far.  I do **not** want to add another facet - I want these both on the x-axis within each facet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similiar to the approach in the post you have linked one option to achieve your desired result would be via two `geom_col` and by converting the x axis variable to a `numeric` like so. However, doing so requires to set the breaks and labels manually via `scale_x_continuous`. Additionally I made use of the `ggnewscale` package to add a second fill scale:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color == "D" | color == "E" | color == "F") %>%
  mutate(dummy = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 13057))

ggplot(mapping = aes(y = price)) +
  geom_col(data = filter(d, dummy == "a"), aes(x = as.numeric(color) - .15, fill = clarity), width = .3) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(name = "a", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_along(levels(d$color)), labels = levels(d$color)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(data = filter(d, dummy == "b"), aes(x = as.numeric(color) + .15, fill = clarity), width = .3) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(name = "b", option = "B", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  facet_wrap(~cut)
```

[image]